# node.js for loop iterating before the function call returns hence creating object issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-crawler, phantomjs

I have node code that fetches the list of websites to crawl, and on iterating through the result, it calls a crawling function written using phantom. But before the crawling function returns the result, the loop is iterating number of times and hence number of calls to crawling function which is not able to handle it. I need immediate answer for my issue.
Please somebody take me out of this well.

my main page code

```
    db.fetch_serviceEntity(function(serviceEntityData){
      if(serviceEntityData!=""){
        serviceEntityData.forEach(function(item){
            console.log(item.website_url);
            db.fetch_entityId(item.id,function(entityId){
                crawler.getCount(item.website_url, item.name, function(rCount){
                    console.log("number of fresh reviews to crawl : ", parseInt(rCount) - parseInt(item.review_count));
                    if(rCount > item.review_count){
                        fetchReviews(item.website_url, entityId.id, parseInt(rCount) - parseInt(item.review_count), function(){
                            db.updateReviewCount(item.id, rCount, function(){
                                process.exit(0);    
                            });
                        });
                    }
                });
             });
          };    
        }); 
      }
      else {
        console.log("No websites to crawl/database error");
      }
      process.exit(0);
    });
```

my crawl function is here

```
    crawler.prototype.crawl = function(webUrl, callback){
    console.log(webUrl);
    this.driver.create({ path: require('phantomjs').path }, function (err, browser) {
      return browser.createPage(function (err,page) {
        return page.open(webUrl, function (err,status) {
          console.log("opened site? ", status);
          page.includeJs('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js', function (err) {
            // Wait for a bit for AJAX content to load on the page. Here, we are waiting 5 seconds.
            setTimeout(function () {
              return page.evaluate(function () {
                //Get what you want from the page using jQuery.
                var reviews = [];
                $('li div.review').each(function () { 
                  if($(this).find('div.ypassport').text()){
                    var d = new Date($(this).find('span.rating-qualifier').text().trim());
                    var temp = {
                        id : $(this).attr('data-review-id'), 
                        entity_id : "",
                        user_id : $(this).attr('data-signup-object').split(":")[1],
                    }
                    reviews.push(temp);
                  }
                });

                return {
                  reviews: reviews
                };
              }, function (err,result) {
                browser.exit();
                callback(result);
              });
            }, 5000);
          });
        });
      });
    });
```

};

I am using ***node-phantom-simple*** for writing crawling function

my problem here is -> because for loop makes number of calls to it, crawl function giving me error that some or other object not created.
for example in the code it says "createpage is not a function of undefined" hence the meaning is browser object not created.
sometimes it says "open is not a function of undefined " hence the "page" object not creating.

Comment: no offence intended, but thats some tough code to read through... Try using separate functions or external libraries, or even go for ES6 and use promises.

Comment: Yeah trying with the promises .. thanks. will let u knw if it wrks

Comment: yes, try promises. Q or Bluebird libraries are solid.  That type of nesting you have is commonly referred as Pyramid of Doom: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_of_doom_(programming)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have async functions, but if you `process.exit(0)` when you return from your first function, all database connections are dropped and no `db.updateReviewCount` is called. So you get more or less arbitrary results, depending on how's the one who closes first.

(Beside that, the code is a callback hell. Maybe you want to create smaller functions and then chain them with a library like `async` or `co` or even by hand.)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, actually i did commented the exit part. while running, and no issue with db, or exit process. only issue is with async part.